# How to put a placeholder in a select dropdrown list using Angular 4?

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular 4 and I'm trying to put a placeholder in a dropdown list using the framework itself, but it's not working.
Here is my code so you can better understand:

```
<select class="form-control" id="ccmonth"                                             
 [(ngModel)]="expenseFilter" (change)="dateFilter(expenseFilter)">

  <option [ngValue]="null" disabled selected>Select Period</option>
  <option [ngValue]="1"> Today </option>
  <option [ngValue]="2">Week</option>
  <option [ngValue]="3">Monthly</option>
  <option [ngValue]="4">Quarter</option>
  <option [ngValue]="5">Year</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you by any chance using Angular Material ? Maybe consider it, have a look at examples here: https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples

Comment: particular for this select drop down i'm not using angular material

Comment: Iam added working example please try and let me know.

Comment: did you tried my answer?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Working Example,

Html File,

```
<select class="form-control" id="ccmonth" [(ngModel)]="expenseFilter" (change)="dateFilter(expenseFilter)">
  <!-- Here iam Added one line -->
  <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled selected>Choose Filter</option>

  <option [ngValue]="1"> Today </option>
  <option [ngValue]="2">Week</option>
  <option [ngValue]="3">Monthly</option>
  <option [ngValue]="4">Quarter</option>
  <option [ngValue]="5">Year</option>

</select>
```

Here is the Demo URL,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-muthutest-vjddiq

Output Screenshot,
[image]

I hope it's solve your problem.

Thanks,
Muthukumar

Answer (score 0):

use `hidden` alosng with `disabled`

```
<option [ngValue]="null" disabled hidden selected> Select Period</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like below.

```
 <option value="" disabled selected>Select Period</option>
```

set by default value of expenseFilter = ""

Answer (score 0):

Cany you try like this

Component:

```
private expenseFilter="";
```

Html

```
<select [(ngModel)]="expenseFilter" class="form-control" (change)="dateFilter(expenseFilter)" required>
  <option value="">Select Period</option>
  <option value="1"> Today </option>
  <option value="2">Week</option>
  <option value="3">Monthly</option>
  <option value="4">Quarter</option>
  <option value="5">Year</option>
</select>
```